# Save entity to Datastore and return it so that any further queries to the same entity are guaranteed to reflect the new updates

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I want to load an entity by key, update it, save it back to Datastore and then return it to the client from an endpoint. However, I want to make absolutely sure that when I return the entity to the client, the updated entity has been saved and propagated across the datastore. This way, if the client queries for that entity with another endpoint immediately after, the updated one will return.

Using Objectify, this is what I have so far:

First I load the entity, update some values and then load it again by the entity key and return it. Will this second load and return of the entity be strongly consistent and reflect the new value?

```
// Load the entity by key
Key<Thing> thingKey = Key.create(Thing.class, id);
Thing thing = ofy().load().key(thingKey).now();

// Update some values
thing.setSomeProperty("new value");

// Save entity
ofy().save().entity(thing);

// Load entity by key - will this loaded entity be guaranteed to reflect the above update?
return ofy().load().key(thingKey).now();
```

Note: I do not want to return the local entity I set the new values to because I do not want the client to potentially query for the entity with the new updates and not get it because they haven't been committed yet due to eventual consistency.

Could this below be another option to achieve the same effect?

```
// Load the entity by key
Key<Thing> thingKey = Key.create(Thing.class, id);
Thing thing = ofy().load().key(thingKey).now();

// Update some values
thing.setSomeProperty("new value");

// Will this save wait until the entity is saved/propagated across the datastore and thus any queries to this entity after this statement will reflect the new update?
ofy().save().entity(thing).now();

// Just return the entity we updated
return thing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between those two sequences. The last `load()` simply loads the same object out of the session cache. You might as well just return the object.

Keep in mind that you need to run this inside a transaction to be safe. Otherwise you run the risk that some other conflicting write will get overwritten and therefore lost between the load and the save.

```
return ofy().transact(() -> {
    Key<Thing> thingKey = Key.create(Thing.class, id);
    Thing thing = ofy().load().key(thingKey).now();

    thing.setSomeProperty("new value");

    ofy().save().entity(thing).now();

    return thing;
}
```

BTW with Firestore, eventual consistency really isn't a thing anymore. But that doesn't mean that data won't necessarily be stale. Technically any piece of data can be stale the moment after it is fetched from the datastore. A transaction ensures a consistent view of the data (ie, all transactions are serializable so data will not be lost).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Just to be clear, using `ofy().save().entity(thing).now()` is synchronous and waits until the entity has guaranteed to be saved and propagated in the datastore (Assuming no other updates to that entity are being made at the same time)? My big concern is that if I create an entity, save it and return it in an endpoint, and then a who user queries for that entity right after does not see it  because of eventual consistency (let's assume the entity won't be updated rapidly at the same time by anyone else so we don't need a transaction).

Comment: If you don't call `now()`, it gets called for you at the end of the request (when the ofy session is closed). If your request completes successfully, the data will be saved.

Eventual consistency doesn't really apply here, get by key has always been strongly consistent and with Firestore, even queries are strongly consistent.

Whenver you do a load/modify/save of an entity, you should use a transaction. Period. I 100% guarantee you that you (or someone after you) will have horrible bugs that look like the system losing data because of not using transactions. Do not play this game.

Comment: Thank you for this comment. Transactions are the way to go. I was more asking my question in an attempt to understand how it works at the lower levels.

Comment: What about a load/delete of an entity? Should one always use a transaction there as well? Otherwise, one person may delete an entity while another person load/modify/save that same entity.

Comment: Also for the load/modify/save, should all three be done in the transaction? Or can you load the entity outside the transaction but then modify+safe it inside the transaction?

Comment: Each transaction needs to be a complete unit of work. Transactions are guaranteed to be serializable, so if you want consistent data you need load/modify/save in the same unit of work. Loading outside a transaction then putting the save in a transaction is equivalent to "just write this data, I don't care if someone else wrote something, obliterate it".

Comment: Load/delete - if you're deleting it, do you need to load it? If your unit of work is "load an entity, check a condition in the data, and delete it" then you need both operations in the transaction.

Comment: I see thank you. What does "serializable" mean exactly in the context of transactions? What do you mean by "Transactions are guaranteed to be serializable"? Does it mean all the work in the transaction is somehow compiled into one request and sent all at once? Or how does it actually work?

Comment: Serializable means that they logically execute one at a time (in serial). Transactions which do not contend for data might actually run in parallel, but your mental model is that the database is single-threaded and only one transaction runs at a time. This is accomplished with optimistic concurrency (in the case of collisions, transactions rollback and repeat) or pessimistic concurrency (transactions take locks on data, other transactions block). Each have ups and downs. Datastore used to be optimistic-only, firestore has both options and I think defaults to pessimistic.

Comment: If load/modify/save transactions weren't serialized, you could have loads and saves interleaved and some transactions would overwrite work done by others. It would look like transactions didn't execute because their updates are lost.

Comment: Thank you that clears things up.

Comment: When you said "The last load() simply loads the same object out of the session cache." - is this a feature of Objectify? Or is this how the underlying Java Datastore API works?

Comment: Actually I found it in the objectify docs that it is a feature: (https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/BasicOperations#the-session-cache). Follow up question: What is a "session"? Does that refer to one endpoint method being run or to an entire app engine instance that has loaded objectify? Is there a way to globally disable the session cache?